# Scraping Multiple Pages without manually getting the amount of pages

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

We currently busy with a property web scrape and trying to scrape multiple pages without manually getting the page range (There are 5 pages)

`for num in range(0,5):`

`url = "https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467/p" + str(num)`

How do you output a URL of all pages without manually typing the page range?

**Output**

https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467/p1
https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467/p2
https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467/p3
https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467/p4
https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467/p4

Maybe using the **ul class="pagination"** in order to count the page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pagination class to fetch the last `a` tag and from that you can fetch `data-pagenumber` and then use it get all the links. Follow the below code to get it done.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url="https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodland-hills-wildlife-estate/bloemfontein/free-state/10467"
url="https://www.property24.com/for-sale/woodstock/cape-town/western-cape/10164"
data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(data.content,"html.parser")
noofpages=soup.find("ul",{"class":"pagination"}).find_all("a")[-1]["data-pagenumber"]
for i in range(1,int(noofpages)+1):
    print(f"{url}/p{i}")
```

Output:
[image: output]
Let me know if you have any questions :)